# Accessing/modifying all instances of a type in Qt/QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

In QML, I have a custom object type (a separate QML file) and I would like a way of accessing and/or modifying each instance of this type. For a very simple example:

MyText.qml:

```
Text {
    height: 100
    width: 100
    color: "red"

    function logStuff() {
        console.log("This is MyText")
    }
}
```

SomePage.qml:

```
MyText {
    id: text1
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    text: "foo"
}

MyText {
    id: text2
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    text: "bar"
}
```

When an event occurs (e.g. a button on SomePage.qml being clicked or a signal being emitted), I would like to be able to change all instances of MyText to have the same value for one property, or call each MyText's `logStuff()` function.

Note: in my actual use case, there are actually several dozen of these instances, and there will be other Text elements which are not instances of MyText.

I have a little experience with jQuery and was hoping there would be something similar to jQuery selectors, but I have been unable to find anything remotely similar. Either a QML or a C++ (or mixed) solution would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest a method using C++.
Since there is no way to get base class of `QML` object you can base the searching on `objectName` property witch is accessible in C++.

Suppose we have base `QML` object:

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Item {
    id: base
    objectName: "BaseItem"
    property int someValue: 0
    onSomeValueChanged: {
        console.log("'someValue' was changed to " + someValue + " for " + base);
    }
}
```

And another QML file, where these objects are used:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300
    id: mainWindow

    Base {
        id: derived1
    }
    Base {
        id: derived2
    }
    Base {
        id: derived3
    }
}
```

The idea is that all derived object inherit the same `objectName` from the base class.

So now you can simply find all of the objects in `C++`:

```
QObject *root = engine.rootObjects().first();
QList<QObject *> list = root->findChildren<QObject *>("BaseItem");
qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());
foreach(QObject *item,list) {
    item->setProperty("someValue",qrand());
}
```

Here I just change the property but you also can call some method with `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your need but I would just use a [Connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#using-the-connections-type) element like so :

SomePage.qml:

```
MyText {
    id: text1
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    text: "foo"
    Connections {
        target: senderItemId
        onFooChanged: logStuff()
    }
}

MyText {
    id: text2
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    text: "bar"
    Connections {
        target: senderItemId
        onFooChanged: logStuff()
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the subject again. How can you access all instances of a type with `Connections` ?

Comment: Are you creating the instances yourself, like in your example? If so then what prevents you from placing a little "Connections" block into each of them like this answer suggests?

Comment: Why putting a Connections in each instance? Put it in the element itself! (i.e. in `MyText.qml`)

Comment: @folibis like RoeyLehman said, if OP is creating the object himself he can easily add the Connections manually. I was suggesting an alternative to accessing the elements in c++.
We could put the Connections directly in the .qml file but then it wouldn't be very flexible, depends on the need I guess.

Comment: Totally agree with @GrecKo (with @peppe improvement :D). I've used `Connection` for this exact purpose and it really worked like a charm. Also, by playing with the `target` property, ternary operator and `null`, you can switch on/off the connection easily creating sub-groups of `Item`s at runtime which are effected/uneffected by the signal.

Comment: May be I miss something here but how is it possible to access __all the instances of specified type__ with `Connections`, as __OP pointed in the subject__? How is it possible to call specified function of all instances of specified type with `Connections` without tricky `onFooChanged: logStuff()`?

Comment: @folibis there's nothing particularly "tricky" about a signal. Period. And answering the first question, it is possible as long as the `Connections` is defined in all the instances (either by directly setting in each instance or by setting it in the element itself, as explained above). The only thing you can argue about is that you need an extra signal...but the OP asked for a solution, either full-QML or not, and a full QML solution requires an extra signal.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API call in Qt to do this (that I could find), but you can find all the QML QObject's by a type using QObject::children() and QMetaObject in C++. Below is an implementation example.

```
QList<QObject *> MySingleton::findObjectsOfComponent(QObject *parent, QQmlComponent *component) const
{
    auto object = component->create(QQmlEngine::contextForObject(parent));
    auto foundObjects = findObjectsOfObject(parent, object);
    delete object;
    return foundObjects;
}

QList<QObject *> MySingleton::findObjectsOfObject(QObject *parent, const QObject *object) const
{
    auto className = object->metaObject()->className();

    QList<QObject*> items;
    for(auto child : parent->children()) {
        if(child->metaObject()->className() == className) {
            items.append(child);
        }

        items.append(findObjectsOfObject(child, object));
    }
    return items;
}
```

Then you should register MySingleton as a QML singleton and use a Component to find the type.

```
Component {
     id: errorLabelComponentId
     ErrorLabel {}
}

Button {
    onClicked: {
        //Un-ignore all error labels
        var errorLabels = MySingleton.findObjectsOfComponent(pageId, errorLabelComponentId)
        for(var i in errorLabels) {
            //ignoreError is a property of ErrorLabel {}
            errorLabels[i].ignoreError = false 
        }
    }
}
```